# Input data into multiple tables using a single form - MS access 2013

Tags: ms-access

I have 5 tables that I would like to input data in. It can only be done with a single form. The fields I want to input in have the same names in all 5 tables, for example:

```
Table 1:
Name
Age
DOB

Table 2:
Name
Age
DOB

Table 3:
Name
Age
DOB

Table 4:
Name
Age
DOB

Table 5:
Name
Age
DOB
```

Is it possible to input data into all of these fields in each table using one textbox for each field?
[image]

Preferably without having to use code but if it cannot be done without it then that would be fine.

Comment: found this topic "Change Data in Multiple Tables" that might be of use to you: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/change-existing-data-by-using-an-update-query-HP005188088.aspx#BMchangemultiple

Comment: I'm sorry but if you really do have 5 tables with the same structure, your data model is broken. You do not try to have redundant data, and five times the same data is more then just redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - but not without coding.
I would put the three text boxes and an 'Update' button on the form - then a bit of code like;

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Dim Tables(4) As String
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set db = CurrentDb

    Tables(1) = "Table1Name"
    Tables(2) = "Table2Name"
    Tables(3) = "Table3Name"
    Tables(4) = "Table4Name"
    Tables(5) = "Table5Name"

    For i = 0 To UBound(Tables) - 1
        strSql = "SELECT a.* FROM " & Tables(i) & "a;"
        Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSql, , dbAppendOnly)
        With rst
            .AddNew
            .Fields("Name") = txtName.Value
            .Fields("Age") = txtAge.Value
            .Fields("DOB") = txtDOB.Value
            .Update
            .Close
        End With
    Next i
    set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Obviously change the table/field/control names to match your form.